# how to pin the chart in analytics as a favourite in azure portal application insights resource

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am working on analytics concept in Application Insights in that when I am run the query’s in Analytics I am getting data as a table format and as well as a chart format but here my question is how to pin the chart in analytics as a favourite in azure portal application insights resource.

This is the chart application insights analytics dashboard.

[image]

I want to pin the above chart to in azure portal application insights metric explorer like below

[image]

Is there any possibilities for this and please give me the suggestions on my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "pin" on analytics charts which can be pinned to Azure portal dashboard. They can't be pinned inside metrics explorer, but all what you can do in metrics explorer you should be able to do on the dashboard where you can pin Analytics charts and MetricsExplorer charts together.  There are few gotchas like the time range on analytics chart is tied to the query used to plot it and doesn't change with the dashboard, but require you to unpin, correct your query and repin, but should work for most of use cases.